# two different joomla Modules that display the same information

Tags: php, joomla, module

I have a module that displays info from a Joomla table. The module has form fields to configure it. Here is the problem:
When I create an instance of this module with the appropriate parameters and display that module in one position, everything works.
Now, I unpublish the module.
I create a second instance of the module (different name) with other parameters and I display it without problem in a second position.
Now when I want to display the two modules in the same page in the two different positions, they then display the data of the first module. The data of the second one are not taken into account.

Here is the module code:

```
<?php
// Pas d'acces direct
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
// Inclure la fonction de recuperation des donnees
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/helper.php';

// Recuperer les choix a partir du fichier XML
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_evenementdmmc');
$params =  new JRegistry($module->params);
$position = $params->get('position', 'g'); // Position du module
$special = $params->get('special', '50');  // Cas speciaux a traiter
$event = $params->get('choixEvent', '0');  // Choix de l'evenement a traiter

// Recuperer les donnees pour les evenements
$lstInfos = ModEvenementdmmcHelper::getInfos($event);

require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_evenementdmmc');
```

The Helper code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Classe Helper class pour le module Evenements du DMMC
 **/
class ModEvenementdmmcHelper
{
    /**
     * Recherche les donnees associees aux choix de l'utilisateur
     *
     * @params - Choix effectues
     *
     * @access public
     */    
    public static function getInfos($param) { 
        // Acces a la BD et recuperation des donnees
        $db = JFactory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $query 
            ->select(array('t.*', $db->quoteName('c1.nomclub', 'nomclub1'), $db->quoteName('c2.nomclub', 'nomclub2')))
            ->from($db->quoteName('#__trntournois', 't'))
            ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__trnclubs', 'c1').' ON ('.$db->quoteName('c1.idclub').' = '.$db->quoteName('t.club1').')')
            ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__trnclubs', 'c2').' ON ('.$db->quoteName('c2.idclub').' = '.$db->quoteName('t.club2').')')
            ->where($db->quoteName('t.idtrn')." = ".$db->quote($param));
        $db->setQuery($query);

        $results = $db->loadObject();

        return $results;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your params call you are getting params data from one module instance therefore you are displaying same data in both modules. Difference between two modules is the naming you did for module. So you need to call params using title of module this way

```
jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
$input  = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$title  = $input->get('title', '', 'string');
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_evenementdmmc', $title);
$params = new JRegistry();
$params->loadString($module->params);
```

Comment: It's not working...
I don't retreive the title of the module and when I vardump($title), it return an empty string.

If I hardcode the title of the module in the getModule function  it works but it's not the solution...

Answer (score 0):

After several readings on the Joomla versions, I found that the management of the module parameters in the Joomla 3.8 version was extremely simplified. The module, when it is created, provides two useful variables.
The first is $module which returns the general parameters of the module:

```
$module ( 
[id] => 153 
[title] => Event futur 
[module] => mod_evenementdmmc 
[position] => bottom-a 
[content] => .....
[showtitle] => 0 
[control] => .....
[params] => .....
...
)
```

The second parameter is called $params and it returns the values entered by the user in the module form (XML file). Here is an example for my case:

```
$params (
[position] => 'd' 
[special] =>  '0'
[choixEvent] => '2'
...
)
```

As a result, the module code has been simplified. Just use the $params variable to retrieve the requested results for this module. Here is the code:

```
<?php
// Pas d'acces direct
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
// Inclure la fonction de recuperation des donnees
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/helper.php';

// Recuperer les parametres choisis par l'utilisateur
$position = $params->get('position', 'g'); // Position du module
$special = $params->get('special', '50');  // Cas speciaux a traiter
$event = $params->get('choixEvent', '0');  // Choix de l'evenement a traiter

// Recuperer les donnees pour les evenements
$lstInfos = ModEvenementdmmcHelper::getInfos($event);

require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_evenementdmmc');
```

Thanks for the advice of the answer, it guided me to the solution.